# new keyword with -1 in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

This is the first time I saw this kind of declaration. I haven't find much information in Google. In one of the existing WPF Applications, where user try to create a new Window he instantiates the class like below. What "-1" means ? What exactly it do ?

```
ProductViewModel viewModel = new ProductViewModel(-1);
```

Comment: just look at the definition of `ProductViewModel` to see what the parameters are.

Comment: It's not a new keyword, its simply a method parameter ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a parameter for the constructor... When you create a class, you can specify zero (default empty constructor is created for you if you don't create at least one) or more constructors. In the constructor you usually set the variables for the class to work with. `-1` usually means that the value isn't set (like a default value), but I believe in that scenario it would be better to create a constructor with an optional parameter like this:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
     // this is our modified constructor
     public ProductViewModel(int productId = -1)
     {
           // do something with the values, probably set some internal field
     }
}
```

A constructor is called always when you create an instance of a class using `new` keyword.

---

Based on the comment, the constructor had parameters declared like this:
`params object[] args`. It's just a fancy syntax for saying `I take variable number of parameters`. You can learn more about `params` here on C# reference: [Params keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: the first answer was better :-D

Comment: @walther Thank you for the answer. It was declared as  public ProductViewModel(params object[] args)
        { /// }

Comment: @WPFRookie, ok, I'll update the answer with this info as well.

Comment: @walther Params Keyword link is helpful. Thanks Again

Comment: @WPFRookie, you're welcome. If this answered your question, you can always mark it as `answer` for future reference. It's considered a good practice on a Q&A site like this.

Answer (score 0):

The depends on the code existing in `ProductViewModel`. I think this `-1` indicates that the programmer intended to create a new `Product`. This `-1` shall be the `ProductId`. If there is an `Id` that is greather than 0 then the details to the product will be loaded. If the Id is `-1` then a new production should be created.

Thats is my idea about what this constructor parameter will do.